# How to pass the number of current page in render()?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I print the pagination box via this:

```
{{ $myarray->render() }}
```

But here is a problem, when I click on each page-link, the URL contains only one argument which is `?page={a number}` .. while I need to keep some other arguments. So I need to pass them in `render()` function to have them on other pages. I mean I want an URL like this

```
http://example.com/products?page=2&order=desc&q=something
```

See? In addition to `page=2` there is also two other arguments *(parameters)* in the URL. How can I do that in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`appends()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) method:

```
{{ $myarray->appends(['order' => 'desc', 'q' => 'something'])->render() }}
```

Comment: One question, why you've written an answer for each question which is attached with `laravel` tag? `:-)` are you working at Laravel company? `;-)`

Comment: @stack no, I'm just a Laravel enthusiast. )